Docker compose watch is not updating my files
My container's are basically dead. I have a vite React frontend and I am trying to update the script tag for my main.jsx to the correct path and it's still showing as what it was hours ago and i've made multiple changes.
Earlier I was using node as the user but due to permission issue I changed to root for development only yet I am still running as node in the container after running docker compose up. Not only does it not update the container but it doesn't even update on the first build.
My html:

....html
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Docker files:
#backend

FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /app


COPY package*.json ./

USER root



RUN npm install

COPY . .



EXPOSE 8000

CMD npm start


#frontend

FROM node:20-alpine



WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./


USER root


RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173

CMD npm run dev

Compose:

version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    depends_on:
      - api

    build: ./frontend

    ports:
      - 5173:5173

    environment:
      VITE_API_URL: http://localhost:8000

    develop:
      watch:
        - path: ./frontend/package.json
          x-initialSync: true
          action: rebuild
        - path: ./frontend/package-lock.json
          x-initialSync: true
          action: rebuild

        - path: ./frontend
          x-initialSync: true
          target: /app
          action: sync

  api:
    depends_on:
      - db

    build: ./backend

    ports:
      - 8000:8000

    environment:
      DB_URL: mongodb://db/anime

    develop:
      watch:
        - path: ./backend/package.json
          x-initialSync: true
          action: rebuild
        - path: ./backend/package-lock.json
          x-initialSync: true
          action: rebuild

        - path: ./backend
          x-initialSync: true
          target: /app
          action: sync

  db:
    image: mongo:latest

    ports:
      - 27017:27017

    volumes:
      - anime:/data/db

volumes:
  anime:


Then I run docker compose up --watch
docker exec -it backend-container sh
$ whoami

node

cat index.html

    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/mern-docker/frontend/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>


docker compose up --build --watch seems to be the answer. Weird how the tutorial I'm watching doesn't make this clear. I was under the impression docker compose up builds your containers even the documentation says it:

Usage docker compose up [OPTIONS] [SERVICE...] .......
Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.

But apparently this isn't true and you need the --build option.

Actually option --watch is optional. When containers are started toggling W button on your keyboard switches between Watch enabled and Watch disabled.
backend-1       | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
backend-1       | INFO:     Application startup complete.
                ⦿ Watch enabled
backend-1       | INFO:     127.0.0.1:38022 - "GET /api/v1/utils/health-check/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
backend-1       | INFO: 


w Disable Watch


